# Joomla - Open just an article and hide modules

Tags: joomla, menu, module

I have a menu with 8 options. Every options have articles related with a category. 
When i open an article, the option menu is selected, and the article load at the bottom of the page showing modules of this option menu.

How i can open the article and deselect the option menu for hide the related modules?

Thanks.

Comment: I have seleted this options. For example:
Main Menu - Home - Section 1 - Section 2 - Section 3 At Section 1 i have 3 modules, Section 2 other 3 modules, Section 3 other 3 modules. This modules are to show Articles. When i want to open an article, this 3 modules are showed, because seccion 3 are selected. How can i show only the content of the article???

Comment: why would you want to show an article within a module on a page? Can't you just create a new menu item and change the type to "single article"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Module Manager in the Joomla Backend and select which pages you want the module to be enabled on or disable the module